# Why is the displacement dependent function stated as the amplitude of a standing wave?

Tags: waves

The equation for stationary wave is :

$y(x,t)=A\sin(kx) \cos(\omega t)$. From this equation the amplitude of the stationary wave is said to be $A\sin(kx)$, in other words the displacement dependent function. So why can't it be the other way around. Like why can't the amplitude be $A\cos(\omega t)$ or in other words the time dependent function?

Answer (score 1):

You could  have $A\cos(\omega t) \sin(kx)$ and talk about the ‘amplitude’ of the time dependent function $\cos$ if you wanted to. It’s a matter of interpretation, the result is the same.

To see this, take out the time dependence (scale it to 1, the same as considering the wave at time $t=0,2\pi,4\pi,...$). Now you just have a wave in space.

As you change $A$ bigger or smaller, you make the wave in space taller or shorter. If you set $A$ negative, then the wave ‘inverts’ and what was positive becomes negative and vice versa.

Now imagine that you move $A$ back and forth, growing and shrinking your wave and inverting it, with a regular motion that can be described in time by $\cos(wt)$. This function is $A\cos(\omega t)$. So then we have added time dependence back in.

What the function $\cos(\omega t)$ does is it scales each point in space by a factor (between -1 and 1) that depends on time in a certain way. So each point in space ‘waves’ up and down between its maximum value and its minimum value.

If you thought of $A$ attached to $\cos$ rather than $\sin$, then the time dependent function scales each point in space between $-A$ and $A$. So the scaling with time becomes stronger if $A$ is large, and weaker if $A$ is small.

Answer (score 0):

The time-dependent cosine makes oscillations in time, it is "a wave". What is its amplitude? It is a factor standing at the time dependent cosine. For each point in space the amplitude is different. "Hand waving" implies constant $x$ (you) and time-dependent hand motion (a wave).

Comment: I liked your example. However you gave an example of space dependent amplitude. So can you explain what will it be for a time dependent amplitude?